# MySQL CONCAT on each field without explicitly doing so

Tags: mysql, csv, concatenation

I have a script that produces a `CSV` file with the results of a MySQL query. The initial problem that I faced, was that Excel interpreted entries `000123` or `(00)`, simply as `123` and `0`. I solved this by following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/568429/excel-csv-import-treating-quoted-strings-of-numbers-as-numeric-values-not-strin) answer.

So now, if my `SELECT` was as follows:

```
SELECT employee.id,
       employee.access_code,
       employee.contact_number,
       employee.buzzer_number
FROM ...
```

I will have to change it to:

```
SELECT CONCAT('\"=\"\"', employee.id, '\"\"\"') AS id,
       CONCAT('\"=\"\"', employee.access_code, '\"\"\"') AS access_code,
       CONCAT('\"=\"\"', employee.contact_number, '\"\"\"') AS contact_number,
       CONCAT('\"=\"\"', employee.buzzer_number, '\"\"\"') AS buzzer_number
FROM ...
```

Which seems clumsy for many fields. Is there a way in which I can wrap every field with `"=""[value]"""` without explicitly doing so in the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: you can set type of each  column on Excel side when import

Comment: @Alex I'm aware of that, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require intervention after the CSV file is generated.

Comment: import-export or any migration process is always unique, so generally you can't predict everything. once you'll change OS on client or server side, or MS Office version, or Country settings on server or client, there is always need to fix something. so imho - it is much eaiser and faster to fix it on Excel side  than to waste time to fix on sql side. because generally there is nothing to fix. the problem is just interpretation of content

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you search

```
SELECT
  "tmp",                    -- Databasename
  "statistics",             -- Tablename
  "CONCAT( '\"=\"\"', ",    -- Pre Field
  ", \'\"\"\"\' ",          -- POST FIELD
  "id"                      -- BLOCKED Fields sep with comma

  INTO @DB, @TABLE,@PRE,@POST,@BLOCKED;


SELECT
  CONCAT('SELECT ', @BLOCKED , ',\n',
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
        @PRE,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        @POST,
        ') AS ' ,
        COLUMN_NAME
    )
  SEPARATOR ',\n') ,
  '\n FROM ', @DB, '.', @TABLE)  
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  @DB AND TABLE_NAME = @TABLE 
  INTO @SQL1;

SELECT @SQL1;  -- only to review the Query

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL1;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is a typo in though, `@dDB` should be changed to `@DB` in the first `INTO`. Update that and I will accept the answer, because it does work